# data is not passing from view to controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

While I click `delete` button to remove a data from laravel blade datatable it passes data with url but in controller it shows empty data.

**Delete button in laravel blade**

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#destroyModal{{ $data->id }}">Delete</button>
```

**delete modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="destroyModal{{ $data->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="destroyModal{{ $data->id }}" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">                                                        
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="{{ route('cat_wise_ingre_measurements.destroy', $data->id) }}" method="POST" class="signup_form row">                                        
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                        <p>Do you really want to delete Ingredient {{ $data->product_categories_name }}?</p> 
                    </div>    
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-square btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-square btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    </div>                    
                </form>                                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::resource('cat_wise_ingre_measurements', 'CategoryWiseIngredientMeasurementController')->middleware('auth');
```

**controller destroy function**

```
public function destroy(CategoryWiseIngredientMeasurement $categoryWiseIngredientMeasurement)
    {
        return $categoryWiseIngredientMeasurement;
    }
```

In `return $categoryWiseIngredientMeasurement;` it return empty data.

I can't find where is the problem?
Anybody help please?

Comment: is this a model? CategoryWiseIngredientMeasurement ??

Comment: Since your resource is called `cat_wise_ingre_measurements` laravel expect a variable called like your resource but in singular. Try renaming your variable to `$cat_wise_ingre_measurement` or `$catWiseIngreMeasurement` (Not sure how it handle the underscore in URL). If you want to change the variable resource name to `$categoryWiseIngredientMeasurement` you have to specify it: `->parameters(['cat_wise_ingre_measurement' => 'categoryWiseIngredientMeasurement'])`

Comment: @Jerson...yes ...`CategoryWiseIngredientMeasurement` is a model

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier....yours one is correct....it conflicts with the resource.
Please give a proper formated answer thus others can understand and I will accept it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Since your resource is called `cat_wise_ingre_measurements` Laravel [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding) expect a variable called like your resource but in singular.

In your case Laravel expect `$cat_wise_ingre_measurement` or `$catWiseIngreMeasurement` (Both will works)

If you want to have `$categoryWiseIngredientMeasurement` as variable name, you need to specify what variable name Laravel should look for on the resource:

```php
Route::resource('cat_wise_ingre_measurements', '')
//->parameters(['cat_wise_ingre_measurements' => 'categoryWiseIngredientMeasurement'])
->parameter('cat_wise_ingre_measurements','categoryWiseIngredientMeasurement')
```

*Note: `paramters() can be used when you have nested resources`*

Answer (score -2):

This is not the correct way to send $data->id in URL parameter the better approach then this is to send hidden input in the form
id}}" hidden>
you can send data to controller in this way easily
im 100% sure this will work

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why do you need a hidden field with the ID if the URL already contains the ID?

Comment: You are not sending id in url parameter this is not the way to send id in url parameter the best solution is to send hidden input in the form which makes your clean and simple

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it. "You are not sending id in url parameter" - what does that mean?

Comment: i said this is not the way to send $data->id as url parameter i told you the most useful and simple way to done your job Thanks

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it. Is there any reason not use a URL parameter? Keep in mind that a good explanation (or even any!) helps other to understand your solution and apply it to their own problems

Comment: Please explain **why** this should not be the correct way. What makes your approach "better"?